# Show Category in Wordpress Portfolium Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories, taxonomy, portfolio

I'm using the [`portfolium-theme`](http://wpshower.com/themes/portfolium/) for Wordpress and I need your help.

I would like to show the portfolio category under the title on the frontpage (loop-portfolio).
The Categories are with taxonomy but I can't figure it out.

[my side](http://florian-koeppen.de/fk/)

the loop-portfolio.php

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $i++; ?>
    <div class="post_home">
<div class="post_home2"></div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="thumb" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(305,145)); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/i/noimage.jpg" width="305" height="145" alt=""/>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>    
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 




    </div>

    <?php if ($i % 6 == 0) echo '<div style="clear: both;"></div>'?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the taxonomy.php

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
    query_posts(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'works' => $term->slug, 'posts_per_page' => -1));
?>

<?php get_template_part('loop-portfolio');  // Loop template for portfolio (loop-portfolio.php) ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

the functions.php

```
    <?php

/*** Top navigation ***/

function register_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('Header', __('Header'));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_menu' );

if ( !is_nav_menu('Header')) {
    $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu('Header');
    wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 1);
}

class extended_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {

        if ( !$element )
            return;

        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

        //display this element
        if ( is_array( $args[0] ) )
            $args[0]['has_children'] = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );

        //Adds the 'parent' class to the current item if it has children
        if( ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] ) )
            array_push($element->classes,'parent');

        $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);

        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);

        $id = $element->$id_field;

        // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
        if ( ($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth+1 ) && isset( $children_elements[$id]) ) {

            foreach( $children_elements[ $id ] as $child ){

                if ( !isset($newlevel) ) {
                    $newlevel = true;
                    //start the child delimiter
                    $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
                    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
                }
                $this->display_element( $child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output );
            }
            unset( $children_elements[ $id ] );
        }

        if ( isset($newlevel) && $newlevel ){
            //end the child delimiter
            $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
            call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
        }

        //end this element
        $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);
    }
}

/*** Commentlist ***/

function commentlist($comment, $args, $depth) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    ?>
    <li id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
        <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class('comment_item clear'); ?>>
            <div class="comment_meta">Posted on <?php printf( __('%1$s'), get_comment_date()); ?> by <?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite>'), get_comment_author_link()) ?></div>
            <div class="comment_text"><?php comment_text() ?></div>
        </div>
<?php
}

/*** Custom Posts ***/

register_taxonomy(
    'works',
    'portfolio',
    array(
        'label' => __('Portfolio Categories'),
        'singular_label' => __('Portfolio Category'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    )
);

register_post_type(
    'portfolio',
    array(
        'label' => __('Portfolio'),
        'singular_label' => __('Work'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'menu_position' => 3,
        'taxonomies' => array('portfolio'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
));

/*** Images ***/

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
update_option('thumbnail_size_w', 305);
update_option('thumbnail_size_h', 145);
update_option('large_size_w', 785);

/*** Misc ***/

function commentdata_fix($commentdata) {
    if ( $commentdata['comment_author_url'] == 'WWW') {
        $commentdata['comment_author_url'] = '';
    }
    if ($commentdata['comment_content'] == 'Write your comment') {
        $commentdata['comment_content'] = '';
    }
    return $commentdata;
}
add_filter('preprocess_comment','commentdata_fix');

function getTinyUrl($url) {
    $tinyurl = file_get_contents("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=".$url);
    return $tinyurl;
}

function get_blogurl() {
    if (get_option('show_on_front') == 'page' && get_option('page_for_posts') != 0) {
        $blogpage = get_page(get_option('page_for_posts'));
        echo $blogpage -> guid;
    } else {
        echo get_option('home');
    }
}

function catlist() { ?>
    <ul class="tags jsddm">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Blog categories</a>
            <ul class="taglist">
                <?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&hierarchical=0&'); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php
}

function n_posts_link_attributes(){
    return 'class="nextpostslink"';
}
function p_posts_link_attributes(){
    return 'class="previouspostslink"';
}
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'n_posts_link_attributes');
add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'p_posts_link_attributes');


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understood what you want, but if you want a drop down menu for portfolio with all the taxonomies justuse the example in the WP codex for [get term link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) Replace 'species' with your taxonomy (hope this is what you need, if not i'll try to help out)
and thats about all you need to do

```
$terms = get_terms('species');
    echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'species').'">'.$term->name.'</a>
</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

PS: if you're not sure what your terms bring back just use print_r($var_name); helps out a lot :)

Comment: Thanks fpr your Answer. I just want to show the portfolio-category under the titel on my frontpage. like here: http://florian-koeppen.de/fk/sof.png

Comment: NO :-( It´s just photoshop

Comment: <div class="term"><?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'works' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {echo $term->name;}?></div>

Comment: i solved it. <div class="term"><?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'works' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {echo $term->name;}?></div>